# Product, Sum, and Digits of a Number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

My aim is to create a program that finds:

- **T(P(n))**: The sum of the product of the digits of all numbers up to n. For example, T(p(5))= p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4)+p(5), where p is a function that calculates the product of all nonzero digits in an integer.
- **T(S(n))**: Sum of all integers up to n, which is pretty easy using the n*(n+1)/2 formula
- **T(D(n))**: Sum of all the digits of all the integers up to n.

I've attempted to complete the first 2 parts, as shown in the codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdjveQ. Javascript shown below:

```
function result() {
var take = document.getElementById("number").value;
  return eval(take.replace(/(\d)(?=\d)/g, '$1+'));
}
function answer() {
document.getElementById('resultfinal').innerHTML = result();
}

function result2() {
var sake = document.getElementById("integers").value;
  var mult = (sake*(sake+1));
  return eval(mult/2);
}

function answer2() {
document.getElementById('sumofn').innerHTML = result2();
}
```

I have no idea:

- **T(P(n))**: How to approach the aspect of adding the p(n) of all integers greater than 0, but less than n.
- **T(D(n))**: Why the n(n+1)/2 formula produces the wrong result
- **T(S(n))**: How I should approach T(D(n))

Comment: Try doing it without `eval`, using `eval` is very poor practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a "brute force" approach is doable, I would first define `P(n)` as a function (se `p` function below) and sum it up using a `for`:

```js
function p(inputN) {
  var n = inputN, m = 1, digit;
  while (n) {
    digit = n % 10;
    if (digit) m *= digit;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  return m;
}
function result3() {
  var sum = 0, i, n = document.getElementById("tpn-input").value;
  for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += p(i);
  }
  return sum;
}
function answer3() {
  document.getElementById('tpn').innerHTML = result3();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tpn-input"><button onClick="answer3()">P(n)</button>
<p id = "tpn"></p>
```

There are other somewhat more readable approaches using string `.split()`, `.filter()` together with `.reduce()`, but the above will certainly be more performatic.

---

And, just for the heck of it, an over-oneliner short implementation:

```js
function p(n) {
  return n.toString().split('').map(Number).filter(i => i).reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
}
function tp(n) {
  return [...Array(+n).keys()].map(i => p(i+1)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
function answer3() {
  document.getElementById('tpn').innerHTML =
      tp(document.getElementById("tpn-input").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tpn-input"><button onClick="answer3()">P(n)</button>
<p id = "tpn"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by trying using some of the array methods to iterate over an array from `1` to `n`. `reduce` would be the most appropriate for this situation: it takes in an array and returns some cumulative value from an operation (or few) done over each element in the array. For example:

```js
function sumUpToN(n) {
  return Array.from({ length: n + 1}, (_, i) => i)
    .reduce((partialSum, thisNum) => partialSum + thisNum);
}
console.log(sumUpToN(5));
```

Generate your arrays using Array.from like that, and then iterate over them with `.reduce`. The first argument is the returned value from the previous iteration of `.reduce`, and the second is the current element in the array. Try using a similar method when you need to iterate over the whole array and come out with a single value on the other end - except instead of plain addition (which will produce the sum of all the elements in the array), use whatever operator(s) are appropriate for the problem in question.